# Modified Levenshtein distance python

Tags: python

Levenshtein distance (LD) is a measure of the similarity between two strings, which we will refer to as the source string (s) and the target string (t). The distance is the number of deletions, insertions, or substitutions required to transform s into t. By default each deletion, insertion or substitution has a value of 1. I'd like to also check for typos and whether š has been written as sh.

This is the formula from wiki which i took as an example for my code:

```
def levenshtein(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        return levenshtein(s2, s1)

    # len(s1) >= len(s2)
    if len(s2) == 0:
        return len(s1)

    previous_row = range(len(s2) + 1)
    for i, c1 in enumerate(s1):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, c2 in enumerate(s2):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1 # j+1 instead of j since previous_row and current_row are one character longer
            deletions = current_row[j] + 1       # than s2
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + (c1 != c2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row

    return previous_row[-1]
```

What i want to achieve is to check whether two characters in source and target string have been swapped and if so then not add +1 to distance, but 0.3 to distance (examples below). In case š is written as "sh" then this would add 0.1 to distance (examples below). I successfully detected whether an š or sh appeared (by also using next character), but i couldn't figure out how to skip a character while keeping the code functional.

Examples:

```
levenshtein("something","summerthings") #would return 4 (delete s, delete m, delete r, replace u -> m.
```

Now this is what i want to achieve:

```
levenshtein("something","soemthing") #should return 0.3 (me and em are swapped)
levenshtein("complicated words","comlpicaet worsd") #should return 0.3+0.3+1+0.3 = 1.9
levenshtein("šomething","shomething") #should return 0.1 as a distance.
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [Soundex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)?

Comment: Not exactly, basically what i'm trying to achieve is to create a prototype of an autocorrect, so in case i type a word like "shomething" (which you can't find in the dictionary), it corrects to "something" (because of 0.1 distance).